# Is it possible multiple connections per one transaction in Postgres? Golang usage

Tags: postgresql, go, transactions

I need to populate table in Postgres concurrently by using multiple connections but in scope of single transaction. Is it possible?

I don't see any way to avoid this bottleneck.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think is possible to share a transaction through different connections. Please explain better what you want to do, maybe adding an example in order to make it easy to understand.

Comment: I have a golang command which parses set of csv files and populates appropriate tables in database. These files a very big. Parser reads files row by row and puts them  to the channel.  Four goroutines takes these results from a channel and make Exec(). If I do  db.Exec() whole process takes 25 minuts, if tx.Exec() more than 4 hours.

Comment: moreover I can't proceed different files in different transactions, because handling of current file must see changes that done by previous files. (Postgres doesn't support READ UNCOMMITED) As a result for whole process I can use only one connection.

Answer (score 1):

I am confident that the transaction did not need to.

But if much want to - you can make a staging table, fill it with several routines, and then in a transaction to transfer data in bulk by using such "insert from select"

Comment: Thank you. I also thought about it. But why do you think that transaction did not need?
By requirements if process fails in some point, we should get database in previous condition.

Comment: I assume that you perform the necessary checks on the downloaded data is not in the business logic layer, or in the stage table, and then load them outside of the transaction.

In any case, long-running transaction over large volumes of data will lead to degradation of performance DBMS.

Comment: You can try to play with the levels of insulation.

1. Select the desired number of connections (the number of threads). Set them to the isolation level "Read uncommitted" [link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/transaction-iso.html) to see the changes made in another threads
2. In each of them start a transaction
3. When the thread complete load data, it must wait for the others and did not commit the transaction
4. When all the threads done - perform commit at all threads.

In the case of SQL-error in one of the thread rollback changes to all threads.